# Running live preview of php files in Brackets text editor

Tags: php, html, wordpress, text-editor, adobe-brackets

I am having issues while running the live preview of some php files on **LOCALHOST**. Like I am working on Wordpress theme and while I am able to set the correct base URL and open the file on the browser through index.php, but I am not able to edit and view the other php files.

For example, I have to open **index.php** which is in http://localhost/test but suppose I want to edit the **header.php** file. I click on the header.php file and it opens a new page in Browser with URL, http://localhost/test/header.php, which **returns a 404 error** through wordpress(OOPS PAGE NOT FOUND!)

I have very little work with index.php and mostly with header, footer, functions and everything else. Although this isn't really a big issue, I can go with the traditional way but I really wanted to utilize this Brackets Feature. **Hope there's something to get past this** :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue this will never open in browser like single file, if you want to check this then header.php and footer.php files are also included into the index.php , you will check from that no need to run them to browser.

Comment: But to edit the header.php file I need to click on it to bring it on workplace area...and this fires a instruction to browser to open header.php.